# I am learning Java and I have some kinds of error"Exception in thread"

Tags: java, exception

public class Number1to4 {

```
/**
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    System.out.printf("%d%n%d%n%d%n%d%n", "1 2 3 4");
    }
}
```

Comment: What do u want to print..??

Comment: Print error message  to get better help

Comment: Then please use try and catch block... Go through Exception handling in java..

Answer (score 4):

There are two problems.

First, your `printf` is expecting 4 arguments, but you are supplying only one.

Second, `%d` says you are expecting the argument to be a number, but you are providing a String.

```
System.out.printf("%d%n%d%n%d%n%d%n", 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

Comment: Why would it be invalid? It prints platform specific line break. Unlike \n.

Answer (score 2):

You can **use** this

```
System.out.printf("%d\n%d\n%d\n%d\n",1,2,3,4);
```

**or**

```
System.out.println(1+"\n"+2+"\n"+3+"\n"+4);
```